# How to write global event handler procedure that makes controls visible/enabled

Tags: delphi

I store controls 'visible' and 'enabled' property in DB table. Depending on user's role I make some controls  not visible/enabled.

**fields of db Table "Controls":** id, role_id, form (varchar), comp_name(varchar), visible (boolean), enable (boolean)

**query qControls:** `select * from controls where form=:form`

**calling of this procedure** from OnShow of main form:

```
 application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
 FORM := 'Form1';
 Form1.showModal;
```

**Called procedure**:

```
procedure RightsOnControls();
    var i:integer;
    
    begin
      fMain.qControls.Close;
      fMain.qControls.Params[0].AsString:= FORM; //FORM is global variable:  FORM:='Form1' 
      fMain.qControls.Open;
      if fMain.qControls.RecordCount>0 then begin
        while not fMain.Controls.Eof do begin
          for I := 0 to form1.ControlCount - 1 do
            if uppercase(form1.Controls[i].Name)= uppercase(fMain.qControlsComp_name.AsString) then
               begin
                form1.Controls[i].Visible:=fmain.qControlsVisible.AsBoolean;
                form1.Controls[i].Enabled:=fmain.qControlsEnable.AsBoolean;
               end;
        fMain.qControls.next;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

My questions are:

1. how make procedure as general event handler,not for only Form1?
2. It finds only controls located on form, not controls located on the panel/Page control (tabsheet). How change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this procedure with the form to handle (f.i. *form1*) and the query (*fMain.qControls*):

```
procedure RightsOnControls(AForm: TForm; AQuery: TFDQuery);

  function FindChildControl(Parent: TWinControl; const ControlName: string): TControl;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    for I := 0 to Parent.ControlCount - 1 do begin
      Result := Parent.Controls[I];
      if SameText(Result.Name, ControlName) then Exit;

      if Result is TWinControl then begin
        Result := FindChildControl(TWinControl(Result), ControlName);
        if Result <> nil then Exit;
      end;
    end;
    Result := nil;
  end;

var
  ctl: TControl;
begin
  AQuery.Close;
  AQuery.Params[0].AsString := AForm.Name;
  AQuery.Open;
  while not AQuery.Eof do begin
    ctl := FindChildControl(AForm, AQuery.FieldByName('Comp_name').AsString);
    if ctl <> nil then begin
      ctl.Visible := AQuery.FieldByName('Visible').AsBoolean;
      ctl.Enabled := AQuery.FieldByName('Enable').AsBoolean;
    end;
    AQuery.next;
  end;
end;
```

In case you don't use FireDAC, change the query type to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Uwe Raabe, thank you for taking the time and effort in writing this code  Your code partially solved my problem- It works for any form, but FindChildControl does not find controls that are located on the panel / pagecontrol (tabsheets).

Comment: I added a recursive FindChildControl implementation.

Comment: Uwe Raabe, Result := FindChildControl(Result, ControlName) causes error: "Incompatible types WinControl and TControl" as Result is TControl, not TWinnControl.

Comment: Uwe Raabe, Great Job!!! You are the best. It works without any exception. I have pagecontrol, on that are located another pagecontrols wich contains tabsheets and on tabsheets are located panel and on this are controls(buttons, edits etc.). It finds all these controls! Thank you very much.